# React context api - share data to with other packages

Tags: reactjs

I have a react-native app (say, MyMobile) and I am also using a react-native library that has some shared components (say, MySharedUX). Both the folders are referring to same react-native versions.

```
package.json (MyMobile){
...
"@MySharedUX" : "file:../MySharedUX"
...
```

In the `MySharedUX` project I have created a pageTracking hook, which uses navigation context. When i invoke the hook from a function-component in `MyMobile` project, I get the navigation object as undefined.

```
export function usePageTracking(pageName: string): void {
    ...
    const navigation = useContext(NavigationContext);  //navigation is undefined.
    // const navigation = useNavigation();  // navigation is undefined.
    ...
```

But if I move the file `usePageTracking` inside `MyMobile` folder, the navigation get populated without any problem.

Though the package `MySharedUX` is executed within the `MyMobile` folder, it doesn't receive the context data.

Is there any way that `MySharedUX` can access the navigation context, without being passed-in as an argument to `usePageTracking` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Context APIs' hooks & methods are subject to in-memory data within APP boundary. If the data needs to be passed on to other packages, or a package that is loaded within your app, you can simply pass the object and re-build a react context inside the package's code.